# How do I add a expiration date validation to this credit card form

Tags: javascript, validation

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>
<label for="month">Expiration Month</label>
<select name="month"> 
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var month = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
for (var m=0; m<month.length; m++)
  {
  document.write("<option>" +month[m]+ "</option>"); 
  }
</script>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<label for="year">Expiration Year</label>
<select name="year"> 
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var year = new Date();
var year2 = year.getFullYear();
for (y=0; y<6; y++)
{
 document.write("<option>" +(year2+y)+ "</option>");
 document.write("<br />");
}

</script>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="reset">
</tr>
</td>
</form>




</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the first response i got when searching for "credit card expiration validation javascript" on Google.

http://perezj.blogspot.com/2008/02/credit-card-expiration-date-validation.html

Always makes me wonder why people post questions on StackOverflow before doing a search on the internet themselves.

Here's the function (if the link doesnt work):

```
function ValidateExpDate()

{

    var ccExpYear = 20 + $F('<%= txtCCExpirationYear.ClientID%>');

    var ccExpMonth = $F('<%= txtCCExpirationMonth.ClientID%>');



    var expDate=new Date();

    expDate.setFullYear(ccExpYear, ccExpMonth, 1);



    var today = new Date();



    if (expDate<today)

    {

        // Credit Card is expire

        return false;

    }

    else

    {

        // Credit is valid

        return true;

    }

}
```

Comment: +1 - A good developer should make an effort to find the answer themselves. On the other side, people consider SO as the definite and credible source for programming queries, just like experts-exchange used to be back in the days, before they filled up all pages with ads and  hid the answers. SO shows up in the top results for most programming related searches. So cataloging this on SO seems perfectly normal to me for future users bumping across this problem.

Comment: @sfjedi - Pasted the function for you.